# Detect if user didn't input anything/deleted input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field where users can input text, when they type something in, and it's valid, an image will appear. Same goes for inputting the wrong text.

I would like to change/remove the image when there is nothing in the input field.

Here's my code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('#input_link').on('mouseout', function(){
    if($.trim($('#input_link').val().length = 0)){
        $('#status_image').attr('src', 'images/link_related/stand_by.png');
    }
    });
```

Comment: You need to use double `=`, like `==` otherwise you are assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: why mouseout? what if the user focuses it, then mouses out (which is very common) then empties the field?

Comment: I think that the 'blur' or 'change' event is what you really need here. It's possible to fill out a text form online using only the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
   $('#input_link').on('mouseout', function(){
     if(!$.trim(this.value).length){
         $('#status_image').attr('src', 'images/link_related/stand_by.png');
     }
   });
```

Your bracket for trim was out of place and you were using assignment operator instead of comparison. I think mouseout might not be a good event to do what you are doing. Use `keyup` or `change` event based on when exactly you want to show the image.

Probably this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
$('#input_link').on('input keyup paste', function () {
    var hasValue = $.trim(this.value).length;
    $('#status_image').attr('src', function () {
        return hasValue ? 'http://placehold.it/20/00ff00' : 'http://placehold.it/20/ff0000';
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HPqRx/)**

Comment: @Sidetik are you trying to change image, if so i have even shorter alternative?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change it.

Answer (score 3):

use `==` or `===` to compare things,

```
if($.trim($('#input_link').val().length == 0)){'
```

Try this,

```
$('#input_link').on('mouseout', function(){
    if($.trim($('#input_link').val()).length == 0){
        $('#status_image').attr('src', 'images/link_related/stand_by.png');
    }
    });
```